# Firebase Notification Icon Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to change the notification icon of the Firebase Cloud notifications in Unity.

I tried copying the icon folder structure from the sample at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main to `Assets/Plugins/Android/Res` so I can test with icons that are known to work, and modifying my Manifest with the

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification"/>` tag.

However it still keeps using the app icon, also when using the default_notification_color tag used in the sample the notifications don't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing the meta-data from the manifest, so only having the icon in the res folder in the app.
Then referencing the icon via the notification JSON:

```
{
    "to": "<Key>",
    "collapse_key": "type_a",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Body of Your Notification",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification",
        "icon": "notification_icon_name",
        "color": "#0000C0"
    }
}
```

This properly showed the icon and changed the color when the status bar was opened.